# PHP alternative syntax for try-catch

Tags: php, syntax

PHP has an alternative syntax for control structures (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and I've been used it very often lately until I got stuck looking for an alternative syntax for try-catch.

Is there any alternative syntax for try-catch? If not, does anyone know why PHP doesn't include it as one of its feature, given it has alternative for other structures?

Comment: No there is not an alternative syntax for a try and catch block. *PHP offers an alternative syntax for **some** of its control structures* <- As in the manual it says, that there is an alternative syntax only for some control structures, but to get the exact reason, you probably have to ask a PHP core developer.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with using the alternative syntax, it may be worth taking a look at the PSR-1/2 coding style guides. Always worth following the universally recommended syntax for the language your using, especially if you plan to corroborate on projects. Although like I said, use what your comfortable with, and use it consistently, but be aware that most open source projects will follow PSR guidelines, and any contributions to them will be expected to follow those guidelines too.

Comment: @jeemusu thanks for the information. But i thought when PHP fully supports the alternative syntax, maybe we can have a new PSR which provides syntax without curly braces (like ruby and phyton). I found that this more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't an alternative syntax for try-catch.  Why?  No one's asked for it.  You can take the first step and [open an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto).

Comment: thanks :)
i thought it would be great if it has this feature, since some developers more convenient with the alternative syntax.

Comment: @WendyAdi it would be impossible in IMO, for instance you don't want to see this kind of logic in a view when using MVC pattern (try...catch) but it shall not be a problem using  other alternative syntax pattern 
`<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>`. In fact in most MVC framework you use it in views

Answer (score 1):

There is no such alternative syntax because IMHO try/catch instruction is not a control conditional structure like if, switch,... The catch block just handles exception.

From php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) :

> Code may be surrounded in a try block, to facilitate the catching of
>   potential exceptions